# Close Form Solution of Quasi Concave Maximization Problem - $ \arg \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}_{++}} \frac{ \ln(1+ax) + \ln(1+bx) }{x+c} $

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have following optimization problem

$$ \arg \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}_{++}} \frac{ \ln(1+ax) + \ln(1+bx) }{x+c} $$

Where $ x $ can have only positive values and $ a, b,c $ are positive constants.

Is there a close form expression possible for optimal $ x $ in the above problem?

I know that the objective function of the problem is a quasi concave function however I wonder if it admits a close form solution.
Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you Need a numerical mathod to solve this Problem. Do you have concrete values fot $a,b,c$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner no i do not have known values of $a,b,c$. But I can solve the following problem in closed form $$\underbrace{\max}_{x}\frac{\ln(1+ax+bx)}{x+c}$$ and I think the close form solution of $x^*$ that I will get for this lower bound of the original problem in my post will be a lower bound on the optimal value of $x$ in my original problem. What do you say? If this is right then at least I can reduce the range of $x$ over which Bisection method is to be used. What your take on this?

Comment: You Can also use that $$\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$$ to simplify your objective function

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes I used that to obtain the lower bound of the numerator that I used in the comment.

Comment: But the first derivative containes the Log-function, this make the difficulties to get the solution of $$f'(x)=0$$

Comment: Can you use that $$\log(x)\le x-1$$ is hold?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes you are right. Actually it involves Lambert W function if the lower bound is to be obtained and a close form solution is possible for the lower bound (that is of following function) $$\frac{\ln(1+ax+bx)}{x+c}$$. But the question is how does the optimal solution for the lower bound compares with the optimal solution of the actual problem. Is it always smaller than (or greater than) the optimal solution of the actual problem in my post. Or is it not possible to say any thing? What do you say about this?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner maybe we can use the relation you mentioned. But I am not sure how

Comment: with your second Ansatz we get $$f'(x)=\frac{a+b}{(x+3) (a x+b x+1)}-\frac{\log (a x+b x+1)}{(x+3)^2}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes it can be solved easily in a close form solution. The answer will be in Lambert W function.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner but I am not sure if your expression for the derivative is perfectly alright

Comment: This Expression is right, i have checked it! And by the way, what is perfectly right?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner i think $3$ should be replaced by $c$.

Comment: Ok this is right, sorry, this whas only one example!,

Comment: $$f'(x)=\frac{a+b}{(x+c) (a x+b x+1)}-\frac{\log (a x+b x+1)}{(x+c)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Dinkelbach's and Schaible's method, but have not found a solution. I still provide my notes so anyone can check them and maybe provide useful comments.

Denote the problem as
$$\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_{++}} \frac{\ln(1+ax) + \ln(1+bx)}{x+c}$$
and define:
$$h(\lambda) = \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_{++}} \{ \ln(1+ax) + \ln(1+bx)-\lambda (x+c) \}$$
Dinkelbach (1967) showed that $h(\lambda) \geq 0$ if and only if:
$$\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_{++}} \frac{\ln(1+ax) + \ln(1+bx)}{x+c} \geq \lambda.$$ The problem now is to find the largest $\lambda$ such that $h(\lambda) \geq 0$.
Since $h$ is concave, its maximum can be found with the first order condition $a/(1+ax) + b/(1+bx) - \lambda = 0$, which simplifies to:
$$\lambda abx^2 + (2ab - 2a\lambda - 2b\lambda) x + (a+b+\lambda) = 0.$$
Plugging this into $h(\lambda)$ and solving for $h(\lambda)=0$ does not give me a closed form solution.

---

Schaible (1974) showed that you can substitute $y = x / (x+c)$ and $t = 1/(x+c)$ to get an equivalent but convex optimization problem:
$$\max_{y \in \mathbb{R}^n_{++}} \{ t \ln(1+ay/t) + t \ln(1+by/t) : y+ct\geq 1 \}.$$
The KKT conditions are:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{at}{t+ay} + \frac{bt}{t+by} - \lambda = 0 \\
\ln(1+ay/t) + \ln(1+by/t) - \frac{a}{t+ay} - \frac{b}{t+ay} - c\lambda = 0 \\
\lambda(1-y-ct) = 0 \\
y+ct \geq 1 \\
\lambda \geq 0
\end{align}$$
I do not find a closed form solution for this either.