# How to linearize a weighted average using Pyomo?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, python, linearization, binary-programming

I'm learning about linear optimization problems using Pyomo. At this time I'm looking to practice and ended up getting stuck in a constraint that contains the weighted average formula. Using this weighted average the solver shows an error that it cannot solve the problem because of the non-linear terms. Below I show how I defined my constraint, which is basically an average that needs to be between a fixed interval.

So, is it possible to rewrite this constraint in a linear format or do I need to use a non-linear solver for this problem? As I'm new to this, please, show me an example of what I should create of variables or constraints. I found this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2753629/1185256) but I do not know if it can solve my problem and how to implement it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Constraint description**
The RSP (quality measure) of each Product Unity (UP) is weighted by the volumes transported daily must be within the limits stipulated by the factory.

Symbols:
f: factory
u: product unity
t: carrier company
d: day

Sets:
days: days of planning (from 1 to 31)
route: a carrier *t*, product unity *u*, factory *f* and day *d*

Parameters:
up_rsp: vector with float a positive value for each product unity *u*

Variables:
delivered_volume: Binary

```
# Constraint definition
def rsp_constraint(model):
  numerator = sum(model.delivered_volume[f,u,t,d]*model.up_rsp[u] for (f,u,t,d) in model.route)
  denominator = sum(model.delivered_volume[f,u,t,d] for (f,u,t,d) in model.route)
  rsp_medio_ponderado = numerator/denominator
  return (factory['rsp_min'], rsp_medio_ponderado, factory['rsp_max'])
model.rsp_constraint = pe.Constraint(model.days, rule = rsp_constraint)
```

**Erro**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ9ZT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Given constants $\ell, u, a_j, b_j$,
a constraint of the form
$$\ell \le \frac{\sum_j a_j x_j}{\sum_j b_j x_j} \le u,$$
where the denominator is positive,
can be linearized by clearing the denominator:
$$\ell \sum_j b_j x_j \le \sum_j a_j x_j \le u \sum_j b_j x_j$$

Comment: If my answer satisfies you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hi @RobPratt. If I understood, I can calculate these summations and then place them in the return like `return (lower, range, upper)`. Is it? I'm trying to visualize it in code. I'll try it asap and give you a reply. tkx in advance.

Comment: I think you will need to split this into two separate $\le$ constraints.

Comment: I'm a novice in this topic. So, could you edit your answer to show an example of how your suggestion looks in code (constraints)?